# Do reputable taxis in Jakarta accept credit card?

Tags: payment-cards, taxis, jakarta

I'll be in Jakarta for a week and I would like to know if reputable taxis like Bluebird taxi accept credit card payment? Is it safe to pay with credit cards? Is there a minimum fare before one can pay with credit card?

Answer (score 8):

If you're taking a taxi from the airport, once you go out from the terminal, you will find a few official "kiosks" for all reputable taxi companies, including BlueBird and SilverBird. BlueBird has some taxis with a poster saying "SHIA Airport Taxi", which stands for Soekarno Hatta International Airport. These ones usually do have a working credit card payment machine. Ask the attendant in the kiosk to provide you a taxi that is capable of processing credit cards, and they'll do that.

In the city, if you are taking a taxi from a mall, most big malls have a blue/silver bird attendant, ask the same and they will try to provide that. Taking a taxi from the street will be a bit difficult to find one with credit card machine. Anyway, calling them to order a taxi is also a *good* option, request one with a credit card machine and they will do that. I think their app also provides that option.

As you can see, I have totally ignored other companies, so should you.

Other safe option, which I do now, is taking an Uber. There's a better chance in having an uber driver who speaks English since many of them are young.

Comment: Why the downvotes, people?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, taxis in Jakarta do NOT accept credit cards, although there are a few exceptions.

Some Blue Bird taxis do have credit card facilities, but always be sure to check before travelling that they are available/working.  In general, you do not want to rely on them having such facilities are they are few and far between.  If travelling from the airport, Blue Bird have a rank outside the terminal where their staff will arrange a taxi for you - if you specifically ask for one with credit card facilities then they will arrange that, but again you might be in for a much longer wait...

Silver Bird, which is Blue Birds "executive" brand do generally have credit card facilities, but again it's very possible that they will be unavailable. Silver Bird cabs are nicer than Blue Bird, but they also change higher rates.

The best option is to have cash available.  There are numerous ATM machines within the airport that you can obtain Indonesian currency from - just make sure you know the current exchange rate as with around 13,000 Rupiah to the USD, the numbers get large very quickly...

Blue Bird do offer a "credit voucher" where you use the voucher to pay the fare, and then it is charged to a credit card on file after the fact - but this is really intended for locals and not for tourists.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for clarifying. I was hoping that credit card is widely accepted by reputable brands like Bluebird because I don't want to file expenses claim later on.

Answer (score 1):

I travelled from the CGK airport in Jakarta using Bluebird taxis. Be careful of drivers that are not reputable.

At the airport, they did not have an office, from what I could see, and I wasn't aware of any available method of paying by card within the taxi.

If you are using the airport, there are ATM's available for cash withdrawals, within the baggage collection and in the arrival lounge.

The bluebird taxi company do appear to have a prepay credit voucher method, I think details are available on their website.